# Crystal Reports 9 - Create parameter fields in batch instead of creating one by one

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to create parameter fields ***(in this case all String)*** for `lbl_AMT_RATE`, `lbl_AVG_COST`, `lbl_AVG_PRICE`, ...... in Crystal Report 9. What I normally did is to create it one by one ***(See Photo)***. How can I create lots of parameters in batch. Let say I have a `.properties` file and stored a list of parameter I want to insert.

XXX.properties

```
lbl_AMT_RATE = Amt. %
lbl_AVG_COST = Avg. Cost
lbl_AVG_PRICE = Avg. Price
. . .
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MilletSoftware for the 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs info. But it seems most of them are modify base and it doesn't seems to be able to create parameters in batch.

I end up using UiPath StudioX to automate this process for me. I used `.xlsx` instead of `.properties` file to store the parameter name. The the automation will take the parameter from `.xlsx` and loop the process of "create parameter field". The only down side is it takes quite some time to do so but thats not an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parameters, consider bringing that information into the report via a database table.

If that is not possible in your case, use a UFL (user function library) and Crystal formulas to look up these values in a text file, excel file, ini file, or registry. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).  Several of these UFLs provide lookup functions, so you can use them in Crystal formulas.

The advantage of using formulas is that:

- you can copy a group of them from one report to another in a
  single step (simple Ctrl-C Ctrl-V)
- there are tools that
  allow you to auto-import them to existing reports.